# Can't get ImageView to show up on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am just learning the RecyclerView and cannot figure out why the imageView with         android:id="@+id/im_item_icon" will not show up on the screen. I even have another imageView that works but when I swap the IDs the original not working view works and the working one will not work. So basically the problem must be with the ID but I cannot figure out why. BTW I got the code from a blog "http://wiseassblog.com/tutorials/2016/03/04/how-to-build-a-recyclerview/"

DerpAdapter.java

```
public class DerpAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DerpAdapter.DerpHolder> {

private List<ListItem> listData;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public DerpAdapter(List<ListItem> listData, Context c){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    this.listData = listData;
}

@Override
public DerpAdapter.DerpHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new DerpHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DerpHolder holder, int position) {
    ListItem item = listData.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.icon.setImageResource(item.getImageResId());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

class DerpHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView title;
    private ImageView icon;
    private View container;

    public DerpHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_item_text);
        icon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.im_item_icon);
        //We'll need the container later on, when we add an View.OnClickListener
        container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cont_item_root);
    }
}
```

DerpData.java

```
public class DerpData {
private static final String[] titles = {"Nothingness cannot be defined",
        "Time is like a river made up of the events which happen, and a violent stream; " +
                "for as soon as a thing has been seen, it is carried away, and another comes" +
                " in its place, and this will be carried away too,",
        "But when I know that the glass is already broken, every minute with it is precious.",
        "For me, it is far better to grasp the Universe as it really is than to persist in" +
                " delusion, however satisfying and reassuring.",
        "The seeker after the truth is not one who studies the writings of the ancients and," +
                " following his natural disposition, puts his trust in them, but rather the" +
                " one who suspects his faith in them and questions what he gathers from them," +
                " the one who submits to argument and demonstration, and not to the " +
                "sayings of a human being whose nature is fraught with all kinds " +
                "of imperfection and deficiency.",
        "You must take personal responsibility. You cannot change the circumstances, the" +
                " seasons, or the wind, but you can change yourself. That is something you" +
                " have charge of."
};
private static final String[] subTitles = {"Bruce Lee",
        "Marcus Aurelius",
        "Meng Tzu",
        "Ajahn Chah",
        "Carl Sagan",
        "Alhazen",
        "Jim Rohn"

};
private static final int icon = R.drawable.ic_tonality_black_36dp;

public static List <ListItem> getListData() {
    List <ListItem> data = new ArrayList <>();

    //Repeat process 4 times, so that we have enough data to demonstrate a scrollable
    //RecyclerView
    for (int x = 0; x  < 4; x++) {
        //create ListItem with dummy data, then add them to our List
        for (int i = 0; i  < titles.length; i++) {
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.setTitle(titles[i]);
            item.setSubTitle(subTitles[i]);
            data.add(item);
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

ListItem.java

```
public class ListItem {
private int imageResId;
private String subTitle;
private String title;
private boolean favourite = false;

public String getSubTitle() {
    return subTitle;
}

public void setSubTitle(String subTitle) {
    this.subTitle = subTitle;
}

public boolean isFavourite() {
    return favourite;
}

public void setFavourite(boolean favourite) {
    this.favourite = favourite;
}

public int getImageResId() {
    return imageResId;
}

public void setImageResId(int imageResId) {
    this.imageResId = imageResId;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

DetailActivity.java

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
}
```

ListActivity.java

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recView;
private DerpAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    recView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rec_list);
    //Check out GridLayoutManager and StaggeredGridLayoutManager for more options
    recView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    adapter = new DerpAdapter(DerpData.getListData(), this);
    recView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

activity_detail.xml

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context="application.binarysoup.jsonpractice.ui.DetailActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_quote_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_quote_attribution"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/lbl_quote_text"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

activity_list.xml

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="application.binarysoup.jsonpractice.ui.ListActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rec_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

list_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cont_item_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:background="@drawable/background_state_drawable"
android:clickable="true"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im_item_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tonality_black_36dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_item_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/im_item_icon"
    android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Sois comme l'eau mon ami"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_item_sub_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_item_text"
    android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Mononc' J"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im_item_icon_secondary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_star_border_black_24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_state_drawable"
    />
```

Comment: `holder.icon.setImageResource(item.getImageResId());` - You never set that `imageResId` on your `ListItem`s in the loop that creates them, so it's 0, and `setImageResource()` just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Can't get ImageView to show up on RecyclerView

You have to initialize imageResId in order to appear it in the recyclerView

```
 for (int i = 0; i  < titles.length; i++) {
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.setTitle(titles[i]);
            item.setSubTitle(subTitles[i]);
//put the code to initialise the imageResId here
            data.add(item);
        }
```